What is the proper way to make a toggle between fast and heavy versions of your model?
I have a model with hairs and modifiers on it.
I set an empty and use it "Hide_Render" property to drive hair and modifiers:

So now I can enable/disable several "heavy" objects and modifiers by one click in Outliner. Light version for animation 30FPS, heavy - for setup scene and lights.
But there is a problem than it goes to Library Override. You can't edit the empty's "Hide_Render" property:

So I ended up with making this empty local. That causes other problems like this one.
So that is the best way to do this (make a switcher between fast and heavy versions of your model)? That is the best practice? How Blender Studio manage such things?

Do you know the "Simplify" options in the render tab, inside the properties panel?


Sure, but I want more precise control over the model. For example, I can disable more modifiers, like solidify, custom GN modifiers. And also, this doesn't work with GN hair.

Understand. You could add a switcher in GN hair to disable it automatically in the viewport or manually, if you want. I mostly add a slider to my node trees, to set the maximum particle amount in the viewport. The final amount will be automatically used in renderings. Just an idea for the GN hair.
